# How to create a project with Bitnami DjangoStack?

Tags: django

I just installed the Bitnami DjangoStack and want to know how to create a new project in Windows.

I tried opening the python.exe (similar to command prompt) and tried typing in:

> > > django-admin.py startproject testproject
> > >       which is what all the articles seem to say to start with.

I am getting an invalid syntax error. I'm assuming I'm missing something very basic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `django-admin.py` from the command prompt.

The Python interactive interpreter (what you get when you open up `python.exe`) is for typing in Python code and running it line by line. If you want to run Python code that is in a file, you need to run it from command prompt.

Note that if that doesn't work, you might need to put `python` before it, and you also might need no specify the full path (usually something like `python C:/Python27/Scripts/django-admin.py`, assuming you're on Python 2.7.)